# Phalcon url parameter missing but action still gets executed

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I am using the latest phalcon version and i am finding it hard to find info on how to make the action not execute when the required parameters are missing as shown below

```
class TestController extends ControllerBase{

public function detailsAction($id) {
        $this->view->SetVar('theid',$id);
    }
}
```

When i access this as below

```
http://localhost/phalcon/test/details
```

The view still gets executed but the id is missing and when i access it via

```
http://localhost/phalcon/test/details/5
```

I get the value 5 .

Can someone please tell me how to make it as "NotFound" or something when the required parameters are missing. And i have a lot of functions with such requirements so if there is a general setting in routing or something i'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks guys

Comment: Can you show us your routing configuration?

Comment: router is the default one. Nothing extra

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the dispatcher event **beforeExecuteRoute** and use some introspection of your target method:

```
        if ($event->getType() == 'beforeExecuteRoute') {
            $cn = $dispatcher->getNamespaceName().'\\'.$dispatcher->getHandlerClass();
            $r = new ReflectionMethod($cn, $dispatcher->getActiveMethod());
            $method_params = $r->getParameters();
            $url_pars = $dispatcher->getParams();
            $pass = true;
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($method_params as $param) {
                if(!$param->isOptional() && !isset($url_pars[$i++])) {
                    $pass = false;
                }
            }
            if(!$pass) {
                return $dispatcher->forward(array('controller' => 'error', 'action' => 'route404'));
            }
            return true;
        }
```

This piece of code is for the dispatcher service.

When you not provide a GET parameter for each action parameters which not have a default value (`isOptional` is false in this case) the `$pass` variable is set to false and you'll be routed to a 404.

This is a case, of course, a more complex condition will allow you more fine grained control.